# REVERSE function in Lisp for minimax-alpha-beta

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, clisp

I have a function that the minimax-alpha-beta does, the fact is that it reads from left to right and I would like it to read backwards and I thought about the "reverse" function but I can not get it to work for me.

The code is the following:

```
(defun minimax-alpha-beta (nodo alpha beta)
  (cond
    ((hoja nodo)
     (let ((val (evalua nodo)))
       (format t "~A " val)
       val))
    ((nodo-min nodo)
     (let ((beta-tmp beta))
       (do ((ch (hijos nodo) (cdr ch)))
           ((or (null ch) (<= beta-tmp alpha)) beta-tmp)
         (let ((r (minimax-alpha-beta (car ch) alpha beta-tmp)))
           (if (< r beta-tmp) (setf beta-tmp r))))))
    ((nodo-max nodo)
     (let ((alpha-tmp alpha))
       (do ((ch (hijos nodo) (cdr ch)))
           ((or (null ch) (<= beta alpha-tmp)) alpha-tmp)
         (let ((r (minimax-alpha-beta (car ch) alpha-tmp beta)))
           (if (< alpha-tmp r) (setf alpha-tmp r))))))))
```

And I have an example tree implemented like this:

```
(defparameter *tree-001*
  '(max ((min ((max ((min (15 14))
                     (min (13 12))))
               (max ((min (11 10))
                     (min (9 8))))))
         (min ((max ((min (7 6))
                     (min (5 4))))
               (max ((min (3 2))
                     (min (1 0)))))))))
```

Where would I have to put the "reverse" so that I would do it the other way around?

Comment: What do you mean by “left to right” and “the other way around”?  What is the expected return value?

Comment: Also, please indent properly. http://gigamonkeys.com/book/syntax-and-semantics.html#formatting-lisp-code

Comment: I mean that the alpha-beta pruning makes the reading of numbers from left to right and the function is done like this, to read the numbers from left to right.

What I want is that I do it the other way round, that I read the numbers from right to left and I do not know how to implement the reverse function.

This should give another way out.

Comment: I indented your code to make sense of it.

Comment: @Roman345 Do not change the question after you have answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that `hijos` returns the children of each node.  This might be the thing you want to reverse.

Comment: Effectively just that is what I want to do but I do not know how to use it or where to put the "reverse" function to get that done

Comment: To reverse the list returned by `(hijos nodo)`: `(reverse (hijos nodo))`.  How do you claim to have written the code in the question without having understood basic function application syntax?

Comment: Well really the function cost me a lot to do it.

I'm new to Lisp and the truth is that it's the first time I ask for help in this way, I usually try everything but sometimes it costs me more.

With what you have advised me, I did this:

                    (do ((ch (reverse(hijos nodo)) (cdr ch)))


It is right?